# wrapping handlbars string with jQuery distorting the string

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to change an email with jQuery. The email itself is using handlebars. I have a table in it, and inside it I have an `each` command that renders number or `<tr>`'s. 
When I wrap the email with jQuery, it is somehow distorting the structure of the email, and basically making it meaningless. 
for example this is before wrapping with jQuery:

```html
<table>
{{#each items}}
  <tr> item.something</tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

and this is after:

```html
{{#each items}}
 
{{/each}}
<table>
  <tr> item.something</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea what could be the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the issue. 
Actually there were two issues:

1. I didn't have `<tbody>` tag
2. The `{{#each}}` should be outside the table.

So it should actually look like this:

```html
{{#each items}}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr> item.something</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{{/each}}
```